# JSON file used to generate selenium code issue

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What i'm trying to do is feed in a JSON file from a website which looks like:

**JSON example**

```
    #{
    #   "register": [
    #       "https:\/\/www.site.com\/register.php|0|0|SEND_URL",
    #       "name|username|0|SEND_USERNAME"
    #   ]
    #}
```

I have only put 2 test fields for testing purposes, each row will consist of 4 parts (0 means ignore this) i'm not sure if i need 4 i may alter as i need in future.

**Breakdown of the meanings:**

```
name = the id of the field
username is the name of the field
0 = ignore
SEND_USERNAME = means sendkeys the username value
```

I have setup a basic function to return the selenium code to interact with the webpage.

**Code:**

```
    def get_identifier(self, identifier):
        final_identifier = ""
        if identifier == "id":
            final_identifier = "find_element_by_id"
        elif identifier == "name":
            final_identifier = "find_element_by_name"
        return final_identifier


    def prepare_fields(self, url_or_identifier, html_identifier, name_this, action_to_take):
        #{
        #   "register": [
        #       "https:\/\/www.thesite.com\/register.php|0|0|SEND_URL",
        #       "name|username|0|SEND_USERNAME"
        #   ]
        #}
        final_string = ""
        if action_to_take == "SEND_URL":
            final_string == self.driver.get(url_or_identifier)
        elif action_to_take == "SEND_USERNAME":
            final_string == self.driver + self.get_identifier(identifier)(html_identifier).send_keys(username)
        print(final_string)
        return final_string


    def mode_register(self, username, password, email, captcha_key, _sleep, _json):       
        try:

            json_string = json.loads(_json)
            if "register" in json_string:
                for register in json_string["register"]:
                    register_parts = register.split("|")
                    self.prepare_fields(register_parts[0], register_parts[1], register_parts[2], register_parts[3])

        except Exception as e: 
            self.print_exception()
```

The error i'm getting is:

**"self.prepare_fields(register_parts[0], register_parts[1], register_parts[2], register_parts[3])"): 'str' object is not callable**

i'm not sure exactly at what part this is referring to, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**self.get_identifier** method returns string as per your code, its not a function

you are treating as function and passing html_identifier, which is wrong.

self.get_identifier(identifier)**(html_identifier)**

Comment: instead, call self.driver.find_element_by_id(html_identifier) / self.driver.find_element_by_name(html_identifier) based on self.get_identifier(identifier) output,

Comment: Thank you! i was over complicating the issue!

Comment: Is there a way i can print to a text file the output of the ```final_string``` i get the error ```unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebDriver' and 'NoneType'``` or should i open a new thread? thank you.